# Unable to wrap the Chinese text on x-axis in D3 bar chart

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js, svg

I've a `D3` bar chart with Chinese and English text on x-axis. Whenever the Chinese text comes, the labels are overlapping. I'm unable to wrap the text into multiple lines. If it's only of English text, I'm able to wrap it. Is there a way to wrap the text if it has Chinese text too?

**Snippet**

```js
var margin = {
  top: 10,
  right: 0,
  bottom: 58,
  left: 40
};
var width = 400 - margin.left - margin.right;
var height = 400 - margin.top - margin.bottom;
var barWidth = 40;

var graph;
var xScale;
var yScale;
var dataSet;

dataSet = [{
    desc: '即使句子没有空格',
    val: 20
  },
  {
    desc: 'Sample text.即使句子没有空格',
    val: 40
  }, 
  {
    desc: 'test3',
    val: 60
  },
  {
    desc: 'test4',
    val: 80
  },
  {
    desc: 'some dummy text here',
    val: 120
  }
];

xScale = d3.scaleBand()
  .domain(dataSet.map(function(d) {
    return d.desc;
  }))
  .range([0, width]);

yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
  .range([height, 0])
  .domain([0, 1.15 * d3.max(dataSet, function(d) {
    return d.val;
  })]);

graph = d3.select("#graph")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("class", "bar-chart")
  .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
  .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");


graph.append("g")
  .attr("class", "x-scale")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
  .call(d3.axisBottom(xScale))
  .selectAll(".tick text")
  .call(wrap, xScale.bandwidth());

graph.append("g")
  .attr("class", "y-scale")
  .call(d3.axisLeft(yScale).tickPadding(10));

graph
  .append("g")
  .attr('class', 'graph-placeholder')
  .selectAll("rect")
  .data(dataSet)
  .enter()
  .append("rect")
  .attr("class", "bar1")
  .attr("height", height)
  .attr("width", barWidth)
  .attr('x', d => xScale(d.desc) + (xScale.bandwidth() - barWidth) / 2);

graph
  .append("g")
  .attr('class', 'graph-main')
  .selectAll("bar1")
  .data(dataSet)
  .enter()
  .append("rect")
  .attr("class", "bar2")
  .attr('x', d => xScale(d.desc) + (xScale.bandwidth() - barWidth) / 2)
  .attr("y", function(d) {
    return yScale(d.val);
  })
  .attr("height", function(d) {
    return height - yScale(d.val);
  })
  .attr("width", barWidth);


graph
  .append("g")
  .attr('class', 'bar-label')
  .selectAll("text")
  .data(dataSet)
  .enter()
  .append("text")
  .text(d => d.val + '%')
  .attr("y", function(d) {
    return yScale(d.val) - 5;
  }).attr('x', function(d) {
    return xScale(d.desc) + ((xScale.bandwidth() - barWidth) / 2);
  });

function wrap(text, width) {
  text.each(function() {
    var text = d3.select(this),
      words = text.text().split(/\s+/).reverse(),
      word,
      line = [],
      lineNumber = 0,
      lineHeight = 1,
      y = text.attr("y"),
      dy = parseFloat(text.attr("dy")),
      tspan = text.text(null).append("tspan").attr("x", 0).attr("y", y).attr("dy", dy + "em");
    while (word = words.pop()) {
      line.push(word);
      tspan.text(line.join(" "));
      if (tspan.node().getComputedTextLength() > width) {
        line.pop();
        tspan.text(line.join(" "));
        line = [word];
        tspan = text.append("tspan").attr("x", 0).attr("y", y).attr("dy", ++lineNumber * lineHeight + dy + "em").text(word);
      }
    }
  });
}
```

```css
.bar-chart {
  background-color: #ccc;
}

.bar2 {
  fill: steelblue;
}

.bar1 {
  fill: #f2f2f2;
}

text {
  font-size: 12px;
  /* text-anchor: middle; */
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div id="graph"></div>
</div>
```

[**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/iamraviteja/r3tcjm4h/) for the same snippet.

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue. Your code seems to work OK for me as is in Chrome, Edge and Firefox on Windows 10. See https://codepen.io/MSCAU/pen/QYKWaq which is just a cut-and-paste of your code.

Comment: @MSC I think you copied JS from the answer below or Fiddle got updated. Please take JS from snippet on SO.

Comment: Ah yes sorry. I'll come back to you in a while.

Comment: @Kaiido beat me to it. Well done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `wrap` function currently splits on white spaces (`/\s+/`) and wraps these parts in their own <tspan> elements.
It needs to be smarter to be able to wrap-words.

The easy fix is to wrap each character in its own <tspan>.

```js
var margin = {
  top: 10,
  right: 0,
  bottom: 58,
  left: 40
};
var width = 400 - margin.left - margin.right;
var height = 400 - margin.top - margin.bottom;
var barWidth = 40;

var graph;
var xScale;
var yScale;
var dataSet;

dataSet = [{
    desc: '即使句子没有空格',
    val: 20
  },
  {
    desc: 'Sample text.即使句子没有空格',
    val: 40
  },
  {
    desc: 'test3',
    val: 60
  },
  {
    desc: 'test4',
    val: 80
  },
  {
    desc: 'some dummy text here',
    val: 120
  }
];

xScale = d3.scaleBand()
  .domain(dataSet.map(function(d) {
    return d.desc;
  }))
  .range([0, width]);

yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
  .range([height, 0])
  .domain([0, 1.15 * d3.max(dataSet, function(d) {
    return d.val;
  })]);

graph = d3.select("#graph")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("class", "bar-chart")
  .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
  .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");


graph.append("g")
  .attr("class", "x-scale")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
  .call(d3.axisBottom(xScale))
  .selectAll(".tick text")
  .call(wrap, xScale.bandwidth());

graph.append("g")
  .attr("class", "y-scale")
  .call(d3.axisLeft(yScale).tickPadding(10));

graph
  .append("g")
  .attr('class', 'graph-placeholder')
  .selectAll("rect")
  .data(dataSet)
  .enter()
  .append("rect")
  .attr("class", "bar1")
  .attr("height", height)
  .attr("width", barWidth)
  .attr('x', d => xScale(d.desc) + (xScale.bandwidth() - barWidth) / 2);

graph
  .append("g")
  .attr('class', 'graph-main')
  .selectAll("bar1")
  .data(dataSet)
  .enter()
  .append("rect")
  .attr("class", "bar2")
  .attr('x', d => xScale(d.desc) + (xScale.bandwidth() - barWidth) / 2)
  .attr("y", function(d) {
    return yScale(d.val);
  })
  .attr("height", function(d) {
    return height - yScale(d.val);
  })
  .attr("width", barWidth);


graph
  .append("g")
  .attr('class', 'bar-label')
  .selectAll("text")
  .data(dataSet)
  .enter()
  .append("text")
  .text(d => d.val + '%')
  .attr("y", function(d) {
    return yScale(d.val) - 5;
  }).attr('x', function(d) {
    return xScale(d.desc) + ((xScale.bandwidth() - barWidth) / 2);
  });

function wrap(text, width) {
  text.each(function() {
    var text = d3.select(this),
      // split on each character
      words = text.text().split('').reverse(),
      word,
      line = [],
      lineNumber = 0,
      lineHeight = 1,
      y = text.attr("y"),
      dy = parseFloat(text.attr("dy")),
      tspan = text.text(null).append("tspan").attr("x", 0).attr("y", y).attr("dy", dy + "em");
    while (word = words.pop()) {
      line.push(word);
      // join with empty string
      tspan.text(line.join(""));
      if (tspan.node().getComputedTextLength() > width) {
        line.pop();
        // join with empty string
        tspan.text(line.join(""));
        line = [word];
        tspan = text.append("tspan").attr("x", 0).attr("y", y).attr("dy", ++lineNumber * lineHeight + dy + "em").text(word);
      }
    }
  });
}
```

```css
.bar-chart {
  background-color: #ccc;
}

.bar2 {
  fill: steelblue;
}

.bar1 {
  fill: #f2f2f2;
}

text {
  font-size: 12px;
  /* text-anchor: middle; */
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div id="graph"></div>
</div>
```

But doing so, we have the same behavior as `word-break: break-all`, that is, it will break even non CJK texts.
What we want is the `word-break: normal` behavior. And for this, the best is to use HTML and CSS.

By generating a dummy HTML element, we can check where every character should be rendered, thanks to [Range.getBoundingClientRect](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Range/getBoundingClientRect) method:

```js
var margin = {
  top: 10,
  right: 0,
  bottom: 58,
  left: 40
};
var width = 400 - margin.left - margin.right;
var height = 400 - margin.top - margin.bottom;
var barWidth = 40;

var graph;
var xScale;
var yScale;
var dataSet;

dataSet = [{
    desc: '即使句子没有空格',
    val: 20
  },
  {
    desc: 'Sample text.即使句子没有空格',
    val: 40
  },
  {
    desc: 'test3',
    val: 60
  },
  {
    desc: 'test4',
    val: 80
  },
  {
    desc: 'some dummy text here',
    val: 120
  }
];

xScale = d3.scaleBand()
  .domain(dataSet.map(function(d) {
    return d.desc;
  }))
  .range([0, width]);

yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
  .range([height, 0])
  .domain([0, 1.15 * d3.max(dataSet, function(d) {
    return d.val;
  })]);

graph = d3.select("#graph")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("class", "bar-chart")
  .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
  .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");


graph.append("g")
  .attr("class", "x-scale")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
  .call(d3.axisBottom(xScale))
  .selectAll(".tick text")
  .call(wrap, xScale.bandwidth());

graph.append("g")
  .attr("class", "y-scale")
  .call(d3.axisLeft(yScale).tickPadding(10));

graph
  .append("g")
  .attr('class', 'graph-placeholder')
  .selectAll("rect")
  .data(dataSet)
  .enter()
  .append("rect")
  .attr("class", "bar1")
  .attr("height", height)
  .attr("width", barWidth)
  .attr('x', d => xScale(d.desc) + (xScale.bandwidth() - barWidth) / 2);

graph
  .append("g")
  .attr('class', 'graph-main')
  .selectAll("bar1")
  .data(dataSet)
  .enter()
  .append("rect")
  .attr("class", "bar2")
  .attr('x', d => xScale(d.desc) + (xScale.bandwidth() - barWidth) / 2)
  .attr("y", function(d) {
    return yScale(d.val);
  })
  .attr("height", function(d) {
    return height - yScale(d.val);
  })
  .attr("width", barWidth);


graph
  .append("g")
  .attr('class', 'bar-label')
  .selectAll("text")
  .data(dataSet)
  .enter()
  .append("text")
  .text(d => d.val + '%')
  .attr("y", function(d) {
    return yScale(d.val) - 5;
  }).attr('x', function(d) {
    return xScale(d.desc) + ((xScale.bandwidth() - barWidth) / 2);
  });


function getLines(text, width) {
  // create a dummy element
  var dummy = d3.select('body')
    .append('p')
    .classed('dummy-text-wrapper', true)
    // set its size to the one we want
    .style('width', width + 'px')
    .text(text);
  
  var textNode = dummy.node().childNodes[0];
  var lines = [''];
  var range = document.createRange();
  var current = 0;
  // get default top value
  range.setStart(textNode, 0);
  var prevTop = range.getBoundingClientRect().top;
  var nextTop = prevTop;
  // iterate through all characters
  while (current < text.length) {
    // move the cursor
    range.setStart(textNode, current+1);
    // check top position
    nextTop = range.getBoundingClientRect().top;
    
    if(nextTop !== prevTop) {
      // new line
      lines.push("");
    }
    // add the current character to the last line
    lines[lines.length - 1] += text[current++];
    prevTop = nextTop;
  }
  // clean up the DOM
  dummy.remove();
  return lines;
}

function wrap(text, width) {
  text.each(function() {
    var text = d3.select(this),
      words = text.text(),
      lines = getLines(words, width),
      line = [],
      lineHeight = 1,
      y = text.attr("y"),
      dy = parseFloat(text.attr("dy"));

    text.text('');
    
    lines.forEach(function(words, lineNumber) {
      text.append("tspan")
        .attr("x", 0)
        .attr("y", y)
        .attr("dy", lineNumber * lineHeight + dy + "em")
        .text(words);
     });
  });
}
```

```css
.bar-chart {
  background-color: #ccc;
}

.bar2 {
  fill: steelblue;
}

.bar1 {
  fill: #f2f2f2;
}

text {
  font-size: 12px;
  /* text-anchor: middle; */
}
.dummy-text-wrapper {
  word-break: normal;
  display: inline-block;
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div id="graph"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: But, the words in English are breaking here. Is there way to break only Chinese words. I think Chinese doesn't have blank spaces to separate words after some google search. Is this the reason for the overlapping?

Comment: @Raviteja You mean you'd want text like `"califragilisticexpialidocious"` to **not** break? The only way would be to use a dummy HTMLElement and apply a word-break keep-all CSS rule on it. Ah I see on Chrome it's all  messed up... On FF it looks ok.

Comment: I understand about the bigger words. As of now, I don't have such bigger words. Where can I put dummy HTMLElement in the svg?